# App/Script to track answers/comments for specific questions?

Tags: discussion, app-request

Is there any app that tracks answers or comments to a specific question and provides an rss feed (or email digest or similar)? I'm only interested in keeping track of certain questions.

Can I use Stack2RSS to generate such a feed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each question on a Stack Exchange site already has a RSS feed.

Just scroll all the way down the page, on the right-hand side you'll find a question feed link:

[image: question feed link]

Comment: @aldrin: It *is* located in a far-off corner of the page.